# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission <File> read) with java web start in signed applet

Tags: java, io, applet, java-web-start, securityexception

I have an applet which is launched by java web start launcher and it's signed too.
I need to do some file operation on the client machine with this applet and doing so an exception is throws. Below is the complete stacktrace

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\FMS\ELSV\JOURNAL\ARBRES\554 read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:544)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:521)
at com.newgen.customs.CNU.deleteSelectiveFiles(CNU.java:121)
at com.newgen.customs.CNU.filter(CNU.java:146)
at com.newgen.backend.Operation.call(Operation.java:83)
at filetransfermanager.FileTransferManagerView$1.windowOpened(FileTransferManagerView.java:48)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following is the code that is being used which is causing problem. (but i dont think its the code)

```
listSaveFile.addAll(Arrays.asList(saveFileArr));
System.out.println("" + listSaveFile);

Collection<File> found = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(sFolderPath),
                         new NotFileFilter(new NameFileFilter(listSaveFile, IOCase.INSENSITIVE)),
                                 TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

for (File f : found) {
   try {
           FileUtils.forceDelete(f);
       } catch (Exception e) {
            delFlag = false;
            System.out.println("" + e.getMessage());
       }
 }
```

Please help. Thanks In advance.

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP?  At what URL can we visit the applet?